# CORS error when using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, api, axios, google-cloud-functions, cors

This is my first question posed, so I apologize if it is not formatted well.

I have been trying to figure out how to deal with the following CORS error, as well as, the CORS preflight error:

*...has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://example.com/' that is not equal to the supplied origin.*

I have spent the last few days reading every question on this topic, and all other documentation I could find on CORS/Cloud Functions/Axios/etc. I am using React, Node, Express, Axios, Google Firebase to host, and Google Cloud Functions.

I am trying to access the PayPal API to gain a bearer token to make further API requests. I understand some of the code pertaining to the request headers might be redundant. I have just been trying to throw anything at this.

Does anyone have any ideas?

The node file - **index.js**

```
const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors")({ origin: true });

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.post("/v1/oauth2/token/", cors(), (req, res) => {
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com/");
  var data = qs.stringify({
    grant_type: "client_credentials",
  });

  var config = {
    method: "post",
    url: "https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token/",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com/",
      Authorization:"xyz",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    data: data,
  };

  axios(config)
    .then(function (response) {
      let bearerToken = response.data.access_token;
      res.status(201).send(bearerToken);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
});

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

The react file  - **payment.js**

```
import axios from "../axios/axios";

 const oneTimePaypalPayment = async () => {
    const response = await axios.post("/v2/checkout/orders");
    console.log(response);
  };
```

The axios file  - **axios.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const instance = axios.create({
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://example.com/",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "https://example.com/",
  },
  baseURL: "https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/api/"
});

export default instance;
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried using the wildcard " * " just to try to get it to work but no luck. I read on another answer that Google Cloud Functions do not recognize the '*' anyways. I have also tried all of the code below, and a lot of other ways to manipulate the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the request header

```
const allowCrossDomain = function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  
    next();
  };

app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.all("*", (req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    next();
  });

  const corsOptions = {
    origin: "https://example.com/",
  };

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.options("/v1/oauth2/token", cors(corsOptions));

app.use(cors({origin:true}));
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use `origin: "https://example.com"` — without the trailing slash

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I just tried that, and unfortunately it doesn't work. I will keep playing with the origin and the trailing slash, and let you know if anything happens.

Answer (score 1):

In a cloud function that you are exporting or working with use below for Origin :

```
exports.your function = async (req, res) => {
  res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```